# Combining jQuery's parent() and add() to act on element and parent together

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dry

Is there a way to use jQuery's `parent()` with `add()`, to act on an element and its parent at the same time?

I'm trying to remove a class from a stored element and its parent. Current solution:

```
$elem.removeClass('foo').parent().removeClass('foo');
```

It doesn't seem particularly DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Is there a more elegant solution?

```
$elem.add('#parentId').removeClass('foo');
```

...should provide the same functionality, but searching the DOM would likely be far more costly to performance than a repeat of `removeClass()`.

Comment: *"but searching the DOM would likely be far more costly to performance"* In this case you aren't searching the dom, you are using `document.findElementById` which is very fast. there's likely very little difference in performance in this case, but, using `.parent().addBack()` definitely looks dryer in my opinion.

Comment: Here is the jsPerf test: [http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass](http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass) . I forgot what I was doing, and tested using `addClass()` rather than `removeClass()`. For chrome at least, `addClass().parent().addClass()` was fastest, shortly behind was the same, but in two separates statements, rather than chained. `add()`, whether from a new DOM lookup or `add($elem.parent())` as well as `addBack()` were much slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is using `addBack()` method, available since jQuery 1.8:

```
$elem.parent().addBack().removeClass('foo');
```

Quoting [**the docs**](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/):

> jQuery objects maintain an internal stack that keeps track of changes
>   to the matched set of elements. When one of the DOM traversal methods
>   is called, the new set of elements is pushed onto the stack. If the previous set of elements is desired as well, `.addBack()` can help.

Note that the similar functionality was available in the earlier versions in `andSelf()` method; it's deprecated since 1.8.

Comment: This works, and looks very elegant. Unfortunately, testing with jsPerf shows that either addBack() must be pretty slow, or addClass() is much slower when there's more than one element.  Unless I made a mistake, among several test cases, the original was the fastest: [http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass](http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/). It's a method that add the previous jQuery object in the current one.

Your code would look like that :

```
$elem.parent().addBack().removeClass('foo');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to present an alternative solution using `.add()` instead of `.addBack()`, you could also do:

```
$elem.add($elem.parent()).removeClass('foo');
```

Comment: Excellent alternative. This is more like what I was expecting. Unfortunately, from my test, this seems the least performative: [http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass](http://jsperf.com/variations-of-jquery-parent-addback-addclass)

Comment: @John that makes sense, I guess it's still good to know that there are multiple options available :)

Comment: Yes, I learned a lot investigating this, and thank you. The performance tests may be completely different if it's a collection of n>1, with their parent, or after a few versions of JQuery, as well.